# Conditional Compilation Based on Type of #define variables

Tags: c++11, gcc, clang, c-preprocessor

Following is clipped version of what I am trying to achive. I am doing some bit arithmatic on a word, I would like to use `__builtin_clrsb` when it is available and the user uses `int` as the word type else compile with slow algorithm. Following compiles with `__builtin_clrsb` regardless of the `WORD` type.

Code uses C++11 but runs on an embedded system so I do not have access to most of `std::` facilities.

```
#if !defined(WORD)
  #define WORD int
#endif

template<size_t S, typename word = WORD>
class my_class {
  ...
  ...
  ...

  size_t do_stuff(){
#if WORD == int && defined(__builtin_clrsb)
    //compile with  __builtin_clrsb
#else
   //comple with slow method
#endif
  }
};
```

Comment: You can only use literals to `#define` macros `int` is keyword. Does your compiler return error?

Comment: @dunajski If you're talking about the `#define WORD int`, that's valid: the macro name is `WORD`, and a macro definition can specify any sequence of valid tokens, not just a literal. (The `#if WORD == int` ... is not.)

Comment: @dunajski no error but `WORD == int` is always true.

Comment: @HamzaYerlikaya aschelper, ouch I didn't know that this macro is valid, my bad.

Comment: Use partial template specialization. See here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue you shouldn't do this:

```
  size_t do_stuff(){
#if WORD == int && defined(__builtin_clrsb)
    //compile with  __builtin_clrsb
#else
    //comple with slow method
#endif
  }
```

rather you should use C++ template specialization to solve this.

```
template<class D, size_t S, class word>
struct my_class_do_stuff_impl {
  D& self() { return *static_cast<D*>(this); }
  D const& self() const { return *static_cast<D const*>(this); }
  size_t do_stuff(){
    //compile with slow method
    //use `self()` instead of `this` to access members of `my_class`
  }
};
#if defined(__builtin_clrsb)
  template<class D, size_t S>
  struct my_class_do_stuff_impl<D,S,int> {
    D& self() { return *static_cast<D*>(this); }
    D const& self() const { return *static_cast<D const*>(this); }
    size_t do_stuff(){
      //compile with  __builtin_clrsb
      //use `self()` instead of `this` to access members of `my_class`
    }
  };
#endif
template<size_t S, typename word = WORD>
class my_class:
  public my_class_do_stuff_impl<my_class<S,word>, S, word>
{
  // don't include do_stuff here
  // if you call do_stuff, do this->do_stuff()
};
```

there are a myriad of reasons to do it this way.  One is that `WORD` being int doesn't force my_class's `word` to be `int`.  Another is that we can do this outside the preprocessor, so we should.

Comment: Although `__builtin_clrsb` might not be known to the preprocessor or compiler at all, in which case a `do_stuff` using it is invalid unless it's only used as a dependent name, which sounds unlikely. Maybe this could work nicely along with some preprocessor work to dummy it out.

Comment: @aschepler Yes, that symbol might only exist when `WORD` is `int`, or similar?  In which case, hopefully there is something different than `WORD` being `int` that distinguishes its existence.

Comment: The original does have `&& defined(__builtin_clrsb)`. It wouldn't be hard to adjust this so that the "slow" implementation is used when there is no such macro (regardless of what `WORD` is), but I don't think it would look exactly the same.

Comment: @aschepler good point.  Easy fix then.  Solved, and it looks exactly the same (well, an extra `#if` around a specialization)

Comment: Oh right, the entire specialization. Yup, that's much simpler than anything I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with

```
#if WORD == int && defined(__builtin_clrsb)
```

besides the fact that `==` works on values, never types, in C++, is that an `#if` is evaluated during the preprocessing step, not compilation, and the preprocessor doesn't really know what `int` is.  The rule for `#if` is that after subsituting all macros and evaluating all `defined()` tests, every identifier-like token other than `true`, even a C++ keyword, that does not name a macro is changed to `0` in order to evaluate the `#if`.

So after substituting some other type for `WORD` (let's say, `short`) and evaluating the `defined` as `1`, the preprocessor is left with

```
#if short == int && 1
```

and then the keywords change to `0`:

```
#if 0 == 0 && 1
```

which is true.

I recommend the template solution shown in [Yakk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54365510/conditional-compilation-based-on-type-of-define-variables/54368042#answer-54368042).

---

[But in case anyone cares, here's a preprocessor-based hack I had here before I saw that answer. It only works if `WORD` does not contain spaces like `long long`.]

```
#define PP_CONCAT1(x,y) x ## y
#define PP_CONCAT(x,y) PP_CONCAT1(x,y)
#define PP_IS_INT_int 1
#define PP_IS_INT_signed 1 /* "signed" alone is the same type as "int" */
#if PP_CONCAT(PP_IS_INT_, WORD) && defined(__builtin_clrsb)
```